# Update + Insert in bigquery using a query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to reproduce this query in Bigquery but the **NOT IN** doesn't support multiple columns selection. So I had the idea of doing it in a Update + Insert (Upsert way) using joins not with an intermediate table, is there a way to mimic the Update + Insert behaviour using Joins ?

Thanks you

```
SELECT
  Make,
  Country,
  Year,
  Month,
  TT.*,
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    STOCK_HISTORIQUE_WEEKLY WE UNION
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    STOCK_HISTORIQUE_MONTHLY MT
  WHERE
    (MT.Make,
      MT.Country,
      MT.Year,
      MT.Month) NOT IN (
    SELECT
      Make,
      Country,
      Year,
      Month
    FROM
      STOCK_HISTORIQUE_WEEKLY) ) TT
```

Comment: **WHERE (MT.Make, MT.Country, MT.Year, MT.Month) NOT IN ( SELECT AS STRUCT  Make,  Country,  Year,  Month  .....**   doesn't work for multiple columns with **NOT IN** ?

Comment: Yes I have tried it multiple times it doesn't

Comment: with **SELECT AS STRUCT**, it should work.  how do you try it with **SELECT AS STRUCT** ?

Comment: `MERGE` is a good way to update and insert new data  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples